# Fetching additional resources from UEFI program when loaded over PXE

Tags: uefi

I have an UEFI program that requires additional files from the same medium it was started from. This works fine when booting from disk or USB; I can get the device path for the program itself by requesting the `EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL` (as `EFI_LOADED_IMAGE_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL`) from the handle passed to `efi_main`, and then I modify the path element at the end to find the other files.

When loading via PXE however, the device path I get only contains the path to the Ethernet adapter and the IP protocol:

```
PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(...,0x1)/IPv4(0.0.0.0)
```

The handle only has `EFI_LOADED_IMAGE_PROTOCOL` and `EFI_LOADED_IMAGE_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL` attached, and the `FilePath` member of the former is an empty path.

- Do I still have an IP configuration at this point, or has this been discarded?
- Can I find out where the current executable was loaded from?
- Can I otherwise express "relative to the current executable"?

In principle I could also repeat the PXE boot, but the PXE menu might contain multiple TFTP servers for different OS installations, so

- Can I recover the "active" PXE menu entry?